# Voronoi diagram

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, voronoi

I'm looking for a source (thesis, paper, video, book) with a detailed, easy to understand, explanation on how to implement a Voronoi driagram in C or C++. The output that I'm looking for is the information to draw one: Position of the vertices, and conectivity of the edges.

I know that maybe I'm asking for too much, but programming is not my field of study, so many of the methods that I have encountered are ambiguous for me. However I'm not looking for a library, Im looking for a method which I can code by myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are courageous, try with "L. J. Guibas and J. Stolfi, Primitives for the manipulation of general subdivisions and the computions of Voronoi diagrams".

The introduction to the "edge algebras" is arduous (even scary) and more than necessary for the standard applications. But if you let that on the side, focusing on the practical implementation of the topological and geometrical primitives (quad-edge graph representation, in-circle test), the Divide & Conquer algorithm should become crystal clear.

The algorithm is bulletproof if you use exact arithmetic, and the approach is powerful. As a byproduct, it will generate the Voronoi diagram and Delaunay triangulation simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to give a look into it.

Comment: I find the boyer-watson algorithm easy to understand.